# Not allowed to load local resource when fetching pdf file from tomcat sprinf application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In spring project, I am generating some pdf file automatically in my application and storing it in $CATALINA_BASE in tomcat server. The path is :

```
D:\Project_Local\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\happyweb\images\User.pdf
```

I have given one hyperlink on webpage to access this file. But when I click on that link it is giving error in Chrome console as below:

```
 Not allowed to load local resource:D:\Project_Local\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\happyweb\images\User.pdf
```

What is the problem and how so resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is not allowing a remote server to trick you into loading a local file. This is to protect the remote server from grabbing files like /etc/passwd and stuff like that. This is a security mechanism that the browser is providing. You may be able to disable that by poking-around in Chrome's settings, but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, perhaps you should have Tomcat serve the PDF file for you instead of giving the user a `file:///` reference to it.